# Axios sends an array of strings instead of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

Axios sends an array of strings instead of an array of objects. I have an array of objects that contains data about the event. I'm trying to send a request to the server via axios, but I get a array of strings insteenter image description heread of objects at the output

```
 let data = {
      title: 'Game',
      subject: 'Some subject',
      date: ['01/01/2021','01/01/2021'],
      years: ['1970', '1970'],
      address: 'None',
      ages: [
              {
                title: 'Men',
                weights: [{page: 0, title: '60'}]
              }
            ]
    };

    api.Create({
      params: data
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
       console.log(err);
    });
```

[api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywwFp.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). We can't help you fix code we can't see. :-)

Comment: Please also post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an incorrect request. I used GET to pass the object, instead of POST, so it converts it to a string. I want to notice that there is an evil community on this site.

Comment: No, there isn't an evil community. It's just that people want to have a great website, without bad content, and so are alerting each time that question (or answer) doesn't meet to stackoverflow rules. The objective is to create a full `question/answer` or all possible problem for all devs

Answer (score 0):

try to:

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(response.data))
```

What you get back from the server is string. you need to parse it.
When you send data to and from a server, it is sent as a 'serialized' string, usually JSON format

That's how server responses work